# How to use Intent.ACTION_DIAL in Kotlin

Tags: android-intent, kotlin

I've been using Java for the longest but I recently switched to Kotlin. Here's my problem: I want to start a dialer intent from my app but the compiler returns this error

*Type mismatch: inferred type is Intent but Context was expected*

This is what I tried:

```
val num = "tel:54646"
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(num)))
```

in java this works:

```
String num = "tel:54646";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(num)));
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Intent but Context was expected

You should add **`activity!!`** before **startActivity**

```
try {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(num))
        activity!!.startActivity(intent)
     } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()

     }
```

Comment: It just worked, after taking a break. I guess the compiler was just exhausted :)